# is there any way to upload folder to github repository using github API

Tags: github, github-api

according to the docs, there is a way to only upload files from GitHub APIs.

```
await octokit.request('PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world',
  path: 'path',
  message: 'message',
  content: 'base64 content'
})
```

but I wanted to upload a folder from GitHub API. since folders can't get encoded to base64(or is there any way?), and I don't want to upload a zip file, is there any way to upload a folder using github API?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (without uploading a zip file) could be to create a file in the new folder using [trees](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#trees) and [contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content), because `git` only tracks folders with files in them.

---

**Example**:

Say we have a user who has a repo with the following contents:

```
├── LICENSE
├── main.py
├── main_test.py
└── README.md
```

If we want to create a file in the `examples` folder called `example.py`, we would issue the following request:

`PUT /repos/<owner>/<repo>/contents/examples/example.go`

The template for the request to create new files is as follows:

`PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

---

Therefore, in your case, you could use the request as the example above to create your new folder with one of its file. Then add the other files to the folder afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Here im using github api put contents to upload.
put contents api link (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)

```
    $src = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tests"; // folder location            
                    // Recursively calling custom copy function
                    // for sub directory 
    $token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//git hub access token
    copy_folder($src,$token);
    function copy_folder($src,$token) 
    {   
    // open the source directory
    $dir = opendir($src);       
    // Loop through the files in source directory
    foreach (scandir($src) as $file) {     
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) 
            {    
                // Recursively calling custom copy function
                // for sub directory 
                copy_folder($src . '/' . $file);  
            } 
            else { 
                  $curl = curl_init();
                  $path = $src . '/' . $file;                           
                        $img = file_get_contents($path);
                        $msg = "files uploads";
                        $post =  array(
                            'sha'=>sha1_file($path),
                            'message'=>'image uploads',
                            'content'=> base64_encode($img),
                            'branch'=>'file uploads '.date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
                            'committer'=> array(
                            'name'=>'raja',
                            'email' => 'test@users.noreply.github.com'
                            )
                            );
                            $data_string_git = json_encode($post);
                    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/'.$path,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string_git,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token ,'User-Agent:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Content-Type: application/json'
                    ),
                    ));   
                    $response = curl_exec($curl);
                  curl_close($curl);
                    // echo $response; 
                    $p_git = json_decode($response,true);
                    // print_r($p_git);                              
            } 
        } 
    }     
    closedir($dir);        
}
```